# Decompiling APK Error Dex2jar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to decompile an apk[by using the commnad dex2jar classes.dex] but it showing this error in the pic.I tried anither apk and it worked but with this one it is not working can someone tell me what is this error and how to solve it ?

http://s7.postimg.org/3kc2ezdqz/Capture.png

Comment: it is showing command deprecated and also you can online websites to decompile easily

Comment: That websites doesnt give the full source code

Comment: [link](http://www.decompileandroid.com) this website gives complete code
When decompile will finish there will be a line below manifest file which says download complete code here click on that it will download complete code

Comment: I tried that,doesnt give me the true code there is some errors,any way thanks

Comment: actually you can't get back 100% original code by decompiling it by any way. Code in android is obfuscated ( modified by changing id's and other things). However you can still get an idea what that code is

Comment: ask it here may be I will not be able to answer it while others can

Comment: Any Idea how Whatsapp plus developers modified whatsapp?